# How to generate .app file for an iPhone/iPad project on Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I want to know the size of my app before sending and validating it on app store. I use 250 viewcontrollers in this project and about 120 Mo of images in resources.

I fear that Apple does not validate because of it size, it is possible? How to create the .app version of this project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Reex, did you find the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

- You can follow app store review guidelines for requirements of app to upload app store. For that follow [review guideline link](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html) .
- I think as per apple documents app that has size more than 2GB will be rejected.

Comment: The maximum limit for apps in the AppStore is 2 GB. However if the app is larger than 50MB users can only download the app via WiFi. The old value for this was 20MB. You mixed it up...

Comment: You can check apple review guidelines. Plz check it my updated answer

Comment: And as you can see, the paragraph says "apps larger than 20MB in size will not download over cellular networks". It does not say that they will be rejected, there is a huge difference. Apps larger than this value will not download via iPhones/iPads connected via 3G network, only via WiFi. Also, this limit was changed to 50MB with the release of the iPad 3.

Comment: See this link: http://hottipscentral.com/you-can-now-download-50mb-files-over-cellular-data-from-the-app-store-and-itunes/

Comment: Ok thanks for giving me information i will update my answer also. Thanks a lot... expecting suggestion in future also..!!!

Comment: I don't have yet read all links given by jake_hetfield but the conclusion is that it is possible to submit my app to appstore without paying the 99$ per year???

Under Xcode, is that a way to know the approximative size of my app??????

Answer (score 0):

You will not be rejected by Apple unless your app is larger than 2GB. However if your app is smaller than 50MB you will get more downloads, since users can download it via iPhones/iPads connected through 3G. If it is larger, only Wi-Fi will work. Users trying to download your app via 3G will get this message:

http://media.hottipscentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/50mb-limit.png

***The fastest way*** to get a hint of the appstore size is to build the project for device and locate your .app file. Usually it is in the bottom of your project navigator. Right-click it and select "show in finder" and check it's size there. This will give a hint of the final value, but it is usually a bit bigger than the final size.

***The most accurate way*** to check your final app store size is to install a valid Ad Hoc distribution certificate for your app, then in Xcode choose Product > Archive.

When your archive is done, you should end up in the Organizer > Archives view. Select your newly created archive.
OBSERVE! There is a value in the Organizer called "Estimated App Store Size: XX MB". DO NOT trust this value, it has been discussed in many other questions on SO and it is not accurate.

Click Distribute... and select to distribute as Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment. Save the file and then browse to the newly save .ipa file in finder. The size of that file will be slightly smaller than your final AppStore size.

***To submit your app*** you need to install and select your App Store distribution certificate, then you choose Archive in the same way as I mentioned above, only now when you have clicked "Distribute", you select AppStore instead.

If you don't have an Apple developer account or know where to get or install your certificate, here is a guide that takes you all the way from registration to submit to appstore:

[how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1)

[how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8045/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2)